# PHP Database Class non-object query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small class, the only thing I want to wrap is making a connection:

```
<?php
/**
 * DB class
 */
class DB {
    private static $_instance = NULL;
    private $_mysqli;

    private function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->_mysqli = new Mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'tradePlace');
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception(
                "Details: " . $e->getMessage()
            );
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }
}
```

But if I do this:

```
$result = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT 
                password, salt, COUNT(id) AS founds
                FROM users
                WHERE username = '' LIMIT 1");
```

I get this error:

> **Fatal error**:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object
>   in **C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\User.php** on line **10**

Why? It should be a object. When I change `return self::$_instance` to  `return self::$_mysqli` I get this error:

> **Fatal error**:  Access to undeclared static property:
>   DB::$_mysqli in **C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\DB.php** on line
>   **20**

I`m a beginner to program in OOP but I dont understand why this not works.

Comment: Static methods are not a part of OOP paradigm. And neither are singletons.

Comment: Question your expectation: Why should it be an object? Please elaborate. Also why do you use global static methods when you want to program OOP? That's normally class oriented programming which is quite different from OOP.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you want to access mysqli::query , re-declare  _mysqli

```
public $_mysqli;
```

then use this code

```
$result = DB::getInstance()->_mysqli->query("SELECT ...
```